# SWTBot Test Configuration Error: Not implemented [multiple displays]

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, swtbot

I am trying SWTBot configuration, but after validating plugins, when I try to run, it gives the following error. Can some one please help.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-03-02 02:15:14.672
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDisplay(Display.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:162)
    at com.qualcomm.qti.qsip.rcp.Application.start(Application.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.eclipse.core.UITestApplication.start(UITestApplication.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: Something have created more that one `Display` object. Only one `Display` is supported.

Comment: Where can I find Display objects?

Comment: The application works fine when I try to run without SWTBot

Comment: Same thing happens for Junit Plugin test, in the same app.